# How to add\get data in admin via reversed relation using GenericTabularInline?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-contenttypes

I can add `Criterias` to a place. How can I add `Places` to a criteria?

Models:

```
class Criterias(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Places(models.Model):
    name = ...

class PlacesToCriterias(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    criteria_group = models.ForeignKey(Criterias)
```

Admin - PLACES part:

```
class PlaceCriteriasInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class PlacesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PlaceCriteriasInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Places, PlacesAdmin)
```

In this case, when I open `Places` admin change page, I can add `Criterias` items to my 'place'.

Admin - CRITERIAS part:

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

In this case, when I open `Criterias` admin change page, I CAN NOT add `Places` item to my 'criteria', because instead of possible `places` I see `criterias`.

How to get `Places` items at `Criterias` admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite easy. `GenericTabularInline` must be changed to `admin.TabularInline`

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

If anyone needs to get dropdown list with selected object, instead of `content_type` and `object_id` fields, the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050111/4992248).