# How to replace content_type and object_id fields by a field with actual object in admin inline?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have inline, which shows data of `contenttype` model, so instead of real objects, I see `content_type` and `object_id` fields. I can `exclude` these fields - this is not a problem, but also I want to get real object as `selected` with another `Places` in a dropdown list. Could anyone tell me, how can I do this?

Model:

```
class Criterias(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Places(models.Model):
    name = ...

class PlacesToCriterias(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    criteria_group = models.ForeignKey(Criterias)
```

Admin:

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

I can add to `CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin` a `form`, something like:

```
class CriteriaPlacesChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    places = forms.ModelChoiceField(PlaceTypesGroups.objects.all(), label='place')
```

but how can I pass\add `object_id` to this form\query in order to get 'selected' place in the dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution.

Add form to `admin.TabularInline`:

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias
    form = CriteriaPlacesChoicesFieldForm  # <- ADDED FORM

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

Form:

```
class CriteriaPlacesChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ct_place_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(PlaceTypesGroups)

    object_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(PlaceTypesGroups.objects.all(), label='places')
    content_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(ContentType.objects.all(), initial=ct_place_type, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_object_id(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['object_id'].pk

    def clean_content_type(self):
        return self.ct_place_type
```

Comment: What does `PlaceTypesGroups` references in your example?