# Django Admin Generic content type multiple models inline form

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes, django-generic-relations

I'm getting started with Django and I'm a bit stuck on a multi-models field, AKA Generic Relation (Content Type)

I have a generic content type "student_solution" that can belong to either:

- a `Org` model
- a `Institution` model
- a `Campus` model

Therefore, in each of those 3 models, I have a reversed relationship as follow, in each `models.py`:

```
# Reverse generic relation - XXX See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations
student_solutions = GenericRelation('student_solution.StudentSolution')
```

> I'm not sure whether this is the right approach, I think so, but a confirmation is welcome :)

---

It's working fine as it is now, but it's not user-friendly in the Django Admin UI, see how it display on django admin, when creating a Student Solution (I would expect a select box showing a `label` field, instead of entering the Content Type ID by hand):

[image: django admin create entity]

When creating either an Org, Institution or Campus, the field doesn't show at all in the Django Admin (so I probably misconfigured something)

I tried following [How to replace content_type and object_id fields by a field with actual object in admin inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030559) to improve the UI by allowing to select the right Content Type and "object" using the object's label. But it doesn't work at this time.

---

`student_solution/models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import fields
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from jsonfield import JSONField

from tfp_backoffice.apps.institution.models import Institution

CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
  Q(app_label='org', model='org') |
  Q(app_label='institution', model='institution') |
  Q(app_label='campus', model='campus')
)

class StudentSolution(models.Model):
  # Dynamic relationship to either Org, Institution or Campus entities
  # XXX https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(
    ContentType,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,  # TODO check if good thing
    limit_choices_to=CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES,
  )
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = fields.GenericForeignKey(
    'content_type',
    'object_id'
  )
```

---

`student_solution/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin

from tfp_backoffice.apps.org.models import Org
from tfp_backoffice.apps.student_solution.forms import StudentSolutionAdminForm, GenericStudentSolutionOwnerChoicesFieldForm
from tfp_backoffice.apps.student_solution.models import StudentSolution

    
class StudentSolutionInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  form = GenericStudentSolutionOwnerChoicesFieldForm
  model = Org  # TODO not sure at all about that, should be either of 3 related ContentTypes (Org | Institution | Campus)
  # This throw error "<class 'tfp_backoffice.apps.student_solution.admin.StudentSolutionInlineAdmin'>: (admin.E202) 'org.Org' has no ForeignKey to 'student_solution.StudentSolution'."


class StudentSolutionAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
  form = StudentSolutionAdminForm
  inlines = [
    StudentSolutionInlineAdmin,
  ]


admin.site.register(StudentSolution, StudentSolutionAdmin)
```

---

`student_solution/forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from tfp_backoffice.apps.org.models import Org
from tfp_backoffice.apps.student_solution.models import CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES, StudentSolution


class StudentSolutionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = StudentSolution
    fields = '__all__'  # Keep all fields    

class GenericStudentSolutionOwnerChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
  ct_place_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Org)  # TODO not sure at all about that, should be either of 3 related ContentTypes (Org | Institution | Campus)

  object_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    Org.objects.all(),
    limit_choices_to=CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES,
    label='Student solution'
  )
  content_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    ContentType.objects.all(),
    initial=ct_place_type,  
    limit_choices_to=CONTENT_TYPE_CHOICES,  # should I use this here?
    widget=forms.HiddenInput()
  )

  def clean_object_id(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['object_id'].pk

  def clean_content_type(self):
    return self.ct_place_type
```

But this code isn't working and throw this error when starting the server

> django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> `<class 'tfp_backoffice.apps.student_solution.admin.StudentSolutionInlineAdmin'>: (admin.E202) 'org.Org' has no ForeignKey to 'student_solution.StudentSolution'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding what you would like to do correctly you should have your `StudentSolutionInlineAdmin` in each of the `Org`, `Institution`, and `Campus` admins and it should be a `GenericTabularInline` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-admin).

So you would have something like this in (for example) your `org/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.admin import GenericTabularInline
from django import forms

from .models import Org
from student_solution.models import StudentSolution

class StudentSolutionInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = StudentSolution
    extra = 1

class StudentSolutionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentSolution
        fields = '__all__'  # Keep all fields 

@admin.register(Org)
class OrgAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StudentSolutionAdminForm
    inlines = [StudentSolutionInlineAdmin]
```

This will allow you to add a StudentSolution related to an `Org` from within the `Org` admin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not able to check if this would work, as I have since changed project. Also, as you're a new member I'll upvote your answer, therefore assuming that your solution is correct. I'll let the community let me know if that's not the case. - I'm doing so because you wrote a clear and detailed answer and only got 10 reputation at the time of writing. I know how hard it is to get some rep' at the beginning on SO and hope that'll make it easier for you. Use your new rights wisely! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look on this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-admin

They have special inline types to use if you are using the content type feature framework